# Why require_once sometimes fails when used within a method?

Tags: php

If I do something like this (it's just a dummy example, but it will be useful to explain the problem):

`variables.php`:

```
<?php
$foo = 'foo';
$bar = 'bar';
?>
```

`SomeClass.php`:

```
<?php
class SomeClass {

    public static function do_something() {
        // XXX Sometimes this works well; but sometimes,
        //     imported variables are null or empty for some
        //     reason within this method's scope
        require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/variables.php' );

        echo '<p>foo = '.$foo.'</p>';
        echo '<p>bar = '.$bar.'</p>';
    }
}
?>
```

**Both files are within the same folder**; although this class is actually required in scripts that are in other folders.

Most of the time it just prints as expected: `foo = foo` and `bar = bar`; but when this class is required by some script that does some heavy operations (filling lots of variables in arrays among other stuff, like calculations), it behaves like the imported variables didn't exist at all (printing `foo =` and `bar =`).

Looking at apache's `error.log`, the `require_once` doesn't throw any error at all; but it prints something like:

```
 PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: foo in /path/to/class_and_variables/SomeClass.php at line 10
 PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: bar in /path/to/class_and_variables/SomeClass.php at line 11
```

**Normally, it works as expected and the variables are correctly imported within `do_something`'s scope; but with some specific scripts, it doesn't.**

It's like (I guess) PHP ran out of memory and destroyed the imported variables silently? I don't know why PHP's `require_once` behaves so strangely sometimes...

Comment: Can you give an example when it fails

Comment: I just didn't know that `require_once` would look at the current file first: I thought it just looks at the available directories in `PATH`. So using `dirname(__FILE__)` looked like a good idea

Comment: @trey The path isn't relative to the "current file", it's relative to the *current working directory*, which isn't always the same as the "current file". Using `__FILE__` to make it absolute is a good idea.

Comment: @deceze: Actually, I used the wrong word: I didn't mean "would look at the current file", but rather "at the current **directory**". Sorry about that

Comment: @trey If you put them both into some sub directory and execute a file outside that sub directory which does `require 'sub/a.php'`, then the *current working directory*, to which all requires are relative, will not be `sub`.

Comment: @trey Again: all `require`/`include` paths are relative to the *current working directory*. That's a thing. It's an important concept. The CWD isn't necessarily the directory your file is in. One way this may be is if your file is in a sub directory and the execution started elsewhere.

Comment: @trey Yeah, it'll work *under some circumstances*, and break *in other circumstances*. To write it robustly so it never breaks you need `__FILE__`.

Comment: @trey Dude…!? ‍♂️ When. The. CWD. !==. Your. File's. Directory.

Comment: @deceze can you link to somewhere with code examples etc.? I [tried](https://github.com/tr3ybake/phpthings) but calling class A which in turn requires class B in a different directory seemed to work (but I may be missing some shizzles)

Comment: @trey https://stackoverflow.com/a/54897164/476,  https://stackoverflow.com/q/2184810/476

Comment: @deceze ahh and the penny drops ty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will be only included on the first execution of the method and not on the second one. The second execution of the method will then have the variables not defined. You should use `require` instead.

Comment: In other words, this will fail if that file has already been included anywhere else previously.

Comment: Thank you very much. Although knowing the difference between `require_once` and `require`, I still fail understanding `require_once`'s behaviour sometimes (now I am ashamed of myself)...

Comment: You should not be ashamed, you should see required_once as a boolean which if the file has already been loaded once , the rest of the requests it will return FALSE because it already has been used "once".