# PHP Functions doesn't recognize includes if outside of functions

Tags: php

i have a problem including MySQL connection file into my 'functions.inc.php'. If i require inside my functions, it works, but functions doesn't work if i include into another page. Like this:

```
function AddToVoteLogs($server_ip){
    include_once 'dbh.inc.php'; // WORK

    CODE ...
}
include_once 'dbh.inc.php'; // dont work
function AddToVoteLogs($server_ip){
    CODE ...
}
```

I try to do with _ *DIR* _ still dont work. Another problem. My functions work in functions.inc.php page but dont work in another pages.

```
function AddToVoteLogs($server_ip){
    include_once 'dbh.inc.php'; // WORK
    $Zip = getUserIP();
    
    $sql = "SELECT last_vote FROM votes WHERE IP = '$Zip';";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if (time() - 86400 >= $row['last_vote']) {
            $hoursIn = 1;
        }
        else {
            $hoursIn = 0;
        }
    }
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Vilnius');
    $dates = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $ipas = getUserIP();
    $sqla = "INSERT INTO vote_log VALUES ('$dates', '$ipas', '$server_ip', $hoursIn);";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqla);
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about JavaScript or PHP? I've added PHP and MYSQL tags, and removed JS/HTML

Comment: For the question to be clear, show exactly what is in each file. How u call it and what is inside dbh.inc.php. Remove the second part if it is not relevant to the first question.

Comment: It usually doesn't matter if its called within a function or not. Frequently its caused by misunderstanding of [include path resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973813/how-does-include-path-resolution-work-in-require-once). Remember that paths are resolved relative to the entry script. You may try "require_once" instead of "include_once". It complains if the file is not found. The error message would show what path it is expecting. Then you can add `__DIR__` to construct the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

In your case (because I do not know the structure of your project), it is better to use only absolute paths for `include_path()`.
To do this, you should declare a constant with a root path in the root of the project and use it in `include_path()` in the future.

For example:

```
// index.php
define('DEFINED_ROOT_PATH', __DIR__.'/your-project-root-dir/'); // or $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT] or any other way
...

// Your custom .php file
include_once(DEFINED_ROOT_PATH. '/lib/dbh.inc.php');
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It usually doesn't matter if its called within a function or not. Frequently its caused by misunderstanding of [include path resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973813/how-does-include-path-resolution-work-in-require-once).

Remember that paths are resolved **relative to the entry script** (e.g. usually `index.php`). Not the `functions.inc.php` here.

To debug this kind of issue, try:

1. Use "require_once" instead of "include_once". It complains if the file is not found. The error message would show what path it is expecting.
2. It's usually more reliable doing paths with the constant `__DIR__`. The constant `__DIR__` is defined against the current script file (functions.inc.php in your case). So unless you move that file around frequently, this is much more reliable.
3. If your `dbh.inc.php` is in the same directory as `functions.inc.php`, the path to it should be:

   ```php
   __DIR__ . '/dbh.inc.php'
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use global variable

Try This

```
function AddToVoteLogs($server_ip){
//include_once 'dbh.inc.php'; // NOT WORK
global $conn; // WORK
$Zip = getUserIP();

$sql = "SELECT last_vote FROM votes WHERE IP = '$Zip';";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if (time() - 86400 >= $row['last_vote']) {
        $hoursIn = 1;
    }
    else {
        $hoursIn = 0;
    }
}
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Vilnius');
$dates = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$ipas = getUserIP();
$sqla = "INSERT INTO vote_log VALUES ('$dates', '$ipas', '$server_ip', $hoursIn);";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqla);
```

}